# hibernate store a Set<Enum> into database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, enums

I'm trying to store a Set of enums into database using hibernate.

The enum is something like

```
public enum SomeEnum { 
    ITEM,
    ITEM2,
}
```

And I have a Hibernate model entity like this

```
@Entity
public class TableObject implements BaseObject {

private Long id;
private Set<SomeEnum> someEnumSet;

@Column(name = "TABLE_COLUMN", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true)
@ElementCollection
public Set<SomeEnum> getSectionSet() {
    return sectionSet;
}

public void setSectionSet(Set<SomeEnum> sectionSet) {
    this.sectionSet = sectionSet;
}
}
```

And I don't think @ElementCollection annotation is correct.
'TABLE_COLUMN' column is of type CLOB in the DB. (Oracle).

Thanks,
Alex.

Answer (score 8):

Try to add @Enumerated annotation:

```
@Entity
public class TableObject implements BaseObject {

   private Long id;
   private Set<SomeEnum> someEnumSet;

   @Column(name = "TABLE_COLUMN", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true)
   @ElementCollection
   @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
   public Set<SomeEnum> getSectionSet() {
      return sectionSet;
   }

   public void setSectionSet(Set<SomeEnum> sectionSet) {
      this.sectionSet = sectionSet;
   }
}
```

It should make hibernate to store your enumes as a Strings (enumes names)